# Terminal blank in xrdp to xfce4 desktop

Tags: 14.04, xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp, remmina

I am using Remmina from my laptop (14.04) to access my home computer (14.04) running xrdp.  I installed xfce4 to be the remote desktop and, mostly, it appears to be working well.  However when I bring up the terminal emulator, all I get is a blank, black screen.  I can't tell if it is black on black or just not available.

I know that Skype always comes up on my home computer when I log in remotely, but I can't see it on my remote computer.  I am guessing that the same thing is happening to the Terminal, or maybe not.  At least I do see the terminal window remotely.

When I was running 12.02, Unity 2D allowed me to access the terminal.

Can this be easily fixed or do I need to find a different GUI for remote access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using xrdp with xfce, it's possible that the default terminal application is indeed writing black on black.  To validate this, simply use another command line utility.  Open xterm instead of terminal and check that everything is working.

In xfce and xrdp, we are guessing that the colors in the default profile preference for termain is black on black. Use the edit menu and unclick the option use colors from system theme.

Answer (score 2):

### Changing the Default Color Schemes will  resolve the issue

Steps:

1. Open Terminal Window.
2. Click Edit in the Menu bar and go to Profile Preferences
3. Move to Colors Tab and un-check **Use Colors from System Theme**

Your Problem will be solved

Comment: This approach works on my machine.
. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Follow this article to install xrdp.
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305
Thanks!!!